# MFC CWinApp::PreTranslateMessage: Identify message (ID: 49390) which causes crash while closing

Tags: mfc, crash, message

The simple question: What kind of message is that? And where does it come from?

The symptoms:

I experience a crash in *CWnd::WalkPreTranslateMessage* while closing
my application. This is caused by a message processed by
*CWinApp::PreTranslateMessage* after the main frame is destroyed and its C++
object is destructed and before MFC processes the WM_QUIT message internally
- I do not call *(Afx)PostQuitMessage*.

I overloaded the *CWinApp::PreTranslateMessage* to trace the messages
passing through.

This happens with VS2005 (32bit) and VS2010 (64bit) and in debug and release mode.

The timeline:

1. *CWinThread::m_pMainWnd* is NULL (been destructed properly)
2. *CWinApp::PreTranslateMessage* is called

   Its parameter *MSG* message* looks like:

   ```
   hwnd: NULL
   message: varies from 49390 to 49401
   wParam: 17
   lParam: looks random
   ```

   => crash in *CWnd::WalkPreTranslateMessage*

At runtime I see messages with that IDs passing through
*CWinApp::PreTranslateMessage*. There is one kind of message
interesting that may help to identify where these messages
come from:

The *MSG* message* looks like:

```
hwnd: NULL
message: 49390
wParam: 17
lParam: looks random at first, though ...
lParam hiword: is incremented by 1 each time the message passes through
lParam loword: is constant
```

These messages seem to be thread messages where hwnd is explicitly NULL.
I still wonder what they are good for, how to stop them filling the message queue
or how to handle them not to crash the application while closing.

Well, for now I handle it like this which is just not right.

```
if (m_pMainWnd)
    return CWinApp::PreTranslateMessage(pMsg);
else
    return FALSE;
```

Please help me identify these messages, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Messages in that range (anything above 0xC000) are returned from `RegisterWindowMessage`. I suspect that you're doing something wrong, since this sort of thing shouldn't happen - and doesn't in properly written MFC applications.

Comment: Thank you! I will have a look at that.